# Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

After installed the Nuxt dev tools I got this error [plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.

this is the nuxt.config.js

```
`// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default {
  loading: {
    color: 'blue',
    height: '5px'
  },
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
            '@nuxt/image-edge',
            '@nuxt/devtools'
          ],
  static: {
    prefix: ''
  },
  image: {
    domains: ['f1.com'],
    dir : '//public'
  },
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
  app: {
    pageTransition: { name: 'page', mode: 'out-in' }
  },
  ssr: true,

  devtools: {
    enabled: true
  }
};
`
```

this is the the package.json

```
`{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "^0.6.1",
    "@nuxt/image": "^0.7.1",
    "@nuxt/image-edge": "^1.0.0-27919678.2f5b64b",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.1.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "nuxt": "^3.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "swiper": "^9.0.3"
  }
}
`
```

I try to follow those istruction, but not working:
You can also disable this overlay by setting server.hmr.overlay to false in vite.config.js.